# Open graph object likes & comments

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm currently developing a native iOS app that integrates with Facebook's Open Graph and uses single sign on. Right now I'm pretty far:

- Single sign on works
- The app receives the following permissions: `user_about_me`, `user_likes`, `read_stream` and `publish_actions`
- The app successfully posts a new Open graph object

I've setup a Facebook App with an Open Graph object/actions and the Open graph debugger shows the green light.

Now the thing is, I would like to keep track of how often this graph object is liked, or how many people commented to it and I'm stuck.

I've read numerous posts and tried both FQL and the Graph API to no success.

For example:

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count,total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat where url='http://example.org/objects/G0DnVgFGfX/'
```

results in:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "url": "http://example.org/objects/G0DnVgFGfX/", 
      "normalized_url": "http://example.org/objects/G0DnVgFGfX/", 
      "share_count": 0, 
      "like_count": 0, 
      "comment_count": 0, 
      "total_count": 0, 
      "commentsbox_count": 0, 
      "comments_fbid": 495931393801732, 
      "click_count": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

No matter how many times it's liked, or commented I always get `0` as a result.

I've also ran the following queries with matching results:

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id IN (SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url = "http://example.org/objects/G0DnVgFGfX/")
```

Returns:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Result is an empty array while `SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url = "http://example.org/objects/G0DnVgFGfX/"` does give me an ID.

To give a bit more context, this is the workflow I'm aiming to create:

- User signs in on mobile app with single sign on
- User creates new object that is stored "locally" and get's posted to Facebook as an Open Graph object
- User receives a push notification when the object is liked or commented at Facebook by a friend
- User views the object and sees the number of times the object is liked or commented
- User views details of the object and can view the comments

Is it even possible to do the things I'd like to do? I find the API to work pretty easy to share stuff with Facebook, but a lot harder to retrieve information.

Of course I have a custom service ready to poll Facebook (or even better, use it's Realtime updates) to make push notifications happen.

Does anyone have any suggestions to point me in the right direction?

**I was looking up comments and likes based upon the Open graph object url and not the ID returned by the iOS method `startForPostWithGraphPath`.**

**Use the ID that is returned to look up comments and likes!**

Answer (score 0):

I was looking up comments and likes based upon the Open graph object url and not the ID returned by the iOS method startForPostWithGraphPath.

Use the ID that is returned to look up comments and likes!